# Cocoa swift: how can set NSTextField to only accept number

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, swift5, xcode10.2

Any of you knows how can set NSTextField to only accept numbers(int)?

Let me explain. I got my NSTextField:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var txtBoxField: NSTextField!
```

But I can type any string and what I want is just to be able to type numbers.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IB, get an `NSNumberFormatter` object and drop it onto your `NSTextField`. This attaches a number formatter object to that text field. In the object browser, it should look like this:

[image]

Now select the `Number Formatter` object and configure the kind, style, and range of numbers that it should allow:

[image]

Choose a style of `None` if you just want whole integers.

If you must do this programmatically, see `NSNumberFormatter` to create and configure the formatter object then use that to set the text field's `formatter` property.